# J-Link debugger hangs when I start it

Tags: debugging, embedded, segger-jlink

Was working great.
Now, I start the J-Link Debugger software, it displays an empty "Terminal" window, and hangs.

I've powered Windows-7 Pro 64-bit laptop completely off, shut off target board power, started board, then laptop... same problem.
Windows connected to J-Link BASE probe v9.3 by USB-SS

Target Device is STM32F427II

Comment: Does Segger not have an Mail address or a hotline? SO is not the service forum of Segger.

Comment: A debugger is a programming tool, so the question is on-topic. However, you will indeed likely get better answers directly from Segger.

Comment: As cliche as it sounds, have you added any USB peripherals lately?  A lot of these tools use Cypress EZUSB as their USB bridge chip, and they do a poor job of customizing the generic driver, making it to where they don't always play nice with other Cypress EZUSB based products.